# How do I add these intensity values per pixel in a fast way?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, cell

Just a quick question that is driving me mad due to its slowness.
I have a cell (300x2), the first column corresponds to the parallel intensity values, and the second one to the perpendicular intensity values. Each cell contains a 128x128 matrix.

So, what I want to do is summing all the intensities of all the matrixes, per pixel. I have the following code but it takes ages to be executed:

```
%Intensity_cell_par_per is the 300x2 cell
%a=128;
%b=128;
%numfiles=300;
I_matrix_par=zeros(128,128);
I_matrix_per=zeros(128,128);

for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        I_par=0;
        I_per=0;
        for k=1:numfiles
            I_par=I_par+sum(Image_cell_par_per{k,1}(i,j,1:end));
            I_per=I_per+sum(Image_cell_par_per{k,2}(i,j,1:end));
        end
        I_matrix_par(i,j)=I_par;
        I_matrix_per(i,j)=I_per;
    end
end
```

Any idea of how I can do it in a fast way?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you say that `Image_cell_par_per{k,1}` is 128x128, but then instead you index it with 3 values. I think we need a [mcve] to help here

Comment: Also, consider accepting your other question answers if they have solved your problems. It will make people more prone to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that the code you posted gives the result you want. This is an easy way of speeding it up:

You can call `sum` as `sum( _ , 3)` to take the whole matrix and sum its 3rd dimension, so you avoid 2 loops. The following code, run with `a=100`,`b=100` and `numfiles=20` runs in `0.0031 seconds` as opposed to `5.17 seconds` with your code, which is about `1660x` faster. I hope this is fast enough.

```
I_matrix_par=zeros(a,b);
I_matrix_per=zeros(a,b);
for k=1:numfiles
    I_matrix_par=I_matrix_par+sum(Image_cell_par_per{k,1},3);
    I_matrix_per=I_matrix_per+sum(Image_cell_par_per{k,2},3);
end
```